# Groovy XMLSlurper issue

Tags: xhtml, groovy, dtd, xmlslurper

I want to parse with XmlSlurper a HTML document which I read using HTTPBuilder. Initialy I tried to do it this way:

```
def response = http.get(path: "index.php", contentType: TEXT)
def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
def xml = slurper.parse(response)
```

But it produces an exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
```

I found a workaround to provide cached DTD files. I found a simple implementation of class which should help [here](http://blog.bensmann.com/http-503-when-parsing-xml):

```
class CachedDTD {
/**
 * Return DTD 'systemId' as InputSource.
 * @param publicId
 * @param systemId
 * @return InputSource for locally cached DTD.
 */
  def static entityResolver = [
          resolveEntity: { publicId, systemId ->
            try {
              String dtd = "dtd/" + systemId.split("/").last()
              Logger.getRootLogger().debug "DTD path: ${dtd}"
              new org.xml.sax.InputSource(CachedDTD.class.getResourceAsStream(dtd))
            } catch (e) {
              //e.printStackTrace()
              Logger.getRootLogger().fatal "Fatal error", e
              null
            }
          }
  ] as org.xml.sax.EntityResolver

}
```

My package tree looks as shown below:

[image]

I modified also a little code for parsing response, so it looks like this:

```
def response = http.get(path: "index.php", contentType: TEXT)
def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
slurper.setEntityResolver(org.yuri.CachedDTD.entityResolver)
def xml = slurper.parse(response)
```

But now I'm getting `java.net.MalformedURLException`. Logged DTD path from CachedDTD entityResolver is `org/yuri/dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd` and I can't get it working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a HTML parse that you could use, in conjunction with XmlSlurper to address these problems

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nekohtml/

Sample useage here

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Testing+Web+Applications

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my parsing issue by using another `XmlSlurper` constructor:

[public XmlSlurper(boolean validating, boolean namespaceAware, boolean allowDocTypeDeclaration)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#XmlSlurper(boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean))

like this:

`def parser = new XmlSlurper(false, false, true)`

In my XML case, disabling the validation (1st parameter `false`) and enabling the DOCTYPE declaration (3rd parameter `true`) did the trick.

Note: