# Confluence plugin not able to find .dtd file

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, dtd, confluence, xmlslurper

I am writing a plugin for our companys Confluence.

In this plugin i need to parse some Confluence Storage Format XML.

Therefor i got the confluence.dtd and some .ent Files from here:
http://www.amnet.net.au/~ghannington/confluence/readme.html

I put the files in resources in my project.
My plugin is written in groovy, and for XML parsing i use the XML Slurper.
But when i run the plugin in Confluence, it cant find the files, because it look for them in:
.../target/container/tomcat6x/cargo-confluence-home/

Just to test if the rest of my plugin is working, i manually copied them there, and everything worked fine.
So, my problem is in fact that my plugin is unable to find the .dtd File (and the .ents).

Have anybody done something like that, or an Idea how to solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745240/groovy-xmlslurper-issue

Comment: I know Confluence is a little finnicky with how you format the address of local folders and files, but I don't think that should matter if your plugin is written in groovy. Still might be worth checking.